# Use jQuery's $.when to do AJAX GET calls on node.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

what I need is to on my server-side(Node.js), make something like this:

```
$.when(
            $.get("https://graph.facebook.com/341446932600922/posts?fields=message,created_time&limit=2", function (dataAcib) {
                allPosts.acib = dataAcib.data;
            }),
            $.get("https://graph.facebook.com/599914540070454/posts?fields=message,created_time&limit=2", function (dataBlusoft) {
                allPosts.blusoft = dataBlusoft.data;
            })
        ).then(function () {
            $.each(allPosts, function () {
                for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
                {
                    $("#divNoticias").append("<p>" + this[0].message + "</p>");
                }

                //- console.log(this[0].message);
            });

            console.log(allPosts);

            var posts = $.makeArray(allPosts.data);
            console.log(posts);
        });
```

I want to accomplish this on server side so that I can send the result to my client-side.

I've used Requestify, and succeded on getting the data of ONE request, but I want to do all my requests (total of 6) assynchronously and when they are finished, procced to the callback.

How can I make all those GET calls and when ALL they are done, do a callback on node server-side?

Thanks

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Question edited

Comment: search `mdn promise` to find documentation on javascript promises, which is what jQuery's deferred's basically do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I have never used Requestify before but I'll take a crack at it based on their documentation.

When working with async, I like to use [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) as it is very useful. We can use it to [map](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#mapSeries) each URL to their responses.

```
var async = require('async'),
    requestify = require('requestify');

var urls = [
    'https://graph.facebook.com/341446932600922/posts?fields=message,created_time&limit=2',
    'https://graph.facebook.com/599914540070454/posts?fields=message,created_time&limit=2'
];
// loop through each URL
async.mapSeries(urls, function (url, done) {
    // for a particular URL, make the request
    requestify.get(url).then(function (response) {
        // pass the response
        done(null, response);
    });
// when all URLs are done
}, function (err, responses) {
    // responses should be an array e.g. [response, response]
    // now do something with responses
});
```

**Edit**

I don't know what kind of data you are getting back from Facebook. For each operation, you could adjust the code by passing only the data you need.

```
async.mapSeries(urls, function (url, done) {
    // for a particular URL, make the request
    requestify.get(url).then(function (response) {
        // pass the response data
        done(null, response.data);
    });
// when all URLs are done
}, function (err, responses) {
    // responses should be a multi-dimensional array e.g. [[data], [data]]
    // here, you could merge and flatten them
    responses = [].concat.apply([], responses);
    console.log(responses);
    // now do something with responses
});
```

Merge and flattening logic came from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865042/1022914)

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer!